# Maximize the Earning

Tags: number-theory, permutations, game-theory

There are two thieves with a total of 1 billion ($10^9$) dollars in a bank vault. Now they must decide how to divide the booty. But there is one problem:
 the thieves have only $M$ minutes to leave the bank before the police arrives. Also, the more time they spend in the vault, the lower the amount they can carry away from the bank. Formally speaking, they can get away with all of the billion dollars right now, but after t minutes they can carry away only $10^9\cdot p^t$ dollars, where $0<p<1$, and at $t = M$, they get arrested and lose all the money.
They will not leave the vault until a decision on how to divide the money has been made.
The money division process proceeds in the following way: at the beginning of each minute starting from the 1st (that is, $t = 0$), one of them proposes his own way to divide the booty. If his colleague agrees, they leave the bank with pockets filled with the proposed amounts of dollars. If not, the other one proposes his way at the next minute etc. To escape arrest, they can only propose plans till the beginning of the $M$th minute (i.e., till $t = M-1$).
Each thief wants to maximize his earnings, but if there are two plans with the same amounts for him, he would choose the one which leads to a larger total amount of stolen dollars.

For example: for $M=2$ and $p=0.5$, if a decision isn't made at $t = 0$, the total amount of money decreases to $0.5*10^9$ at $t = 1$ which leads to a situation worse than the given solution, so each thief would get 500000000 each.

How should I calculate this for any value of $M$ and $p$.

Comment: If $M$ is an even number, then the first thief proposes to take all money, since the other thief doesn't have the option to reply at time $M$ (and he agrees at the first plan since he gets 0 anyways).

Comment: @Marc  the example i have explain above does not satisfy your description

Comment: To make sure I get the situation:   With one minute to go, the proposing thief is free to say "I get everything we can carry, less 1 dollar .  you get 1 dollar."  His partner either takes the deal or gets nothing, so he takes it.  Is that correct?

Comment: You could even say he gets nothing since he accepts the proposal which gives the largest total value right?

Comment: @Marc yup Each thief wants to maximize his earnings, but if there are two plans with the same amounts for him, he would choose the one which leads to a larger total amount of stolen dollars

Comment: @Marc.  Good point.  But is this accurate?  The OP speaks of choosing between two plans, where if I understand the problem there is never more than one plan on the table at any given moment.  Well, I guess the choice could be "this plan or whatever might come next".

Comment: if the amount is does not go beyond billion/2 after m-1 sec than if M is even  1 thief get that money and second will get zero and same for odd also  else  they will dvide equally, i am correct or wrong

Comment: So thief 1 and 2 realise that at time $M-1$, for $M$ even, thief 1 will claim all the money and thief 2 gets nothing. Therefore both realise at the start that thief 1 will never offer any money at all to the second. Since the second thief picks the proposal with highest total return he goes for the first proposal where thief 1 gets the whole billion. What step is incorrect here according to your logic xzaas?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever gets to propose the last distribution can walk away with $p^{M-1}$ of the loot (I'll omit the one billion), so the other one has to give that sum at the $M-2$ point if he wants to get anything, this means he can get $p^{M-2}-p^{M-1}=p^{M-2}(1-p)$ at the $M-2$ point. We can keep this line of thought and go one more step back in which the proposing thief can get away with $p^{M-3}-p^{M-2}(1-p)=p^{M-3}(1-p+p^2)$ etc.

The general term for the proposal at $T$ steps before the end can be shown to be $p^{M-T}(1-p+p^2-p^3...+(-1)^{T-1}p^{T-1}$ (by simple induction), where the last term is a finite geometric series with $q=-p$, and so for $T=M$ we get $\frac{1+(-1)^{M-1}p^M}{1+p}$.